# how to get label from value selected Picker React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i try to show the Label and not the value for a Picker i can't !
Anyone have a solution please ?
the code

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
      </Picker>
```

Comment: have you tried using only one argument like `onValueChange={(item) => setSelectedValue(item)`

Comment: <Text> {selectedValue} </Text> yes it's show Value => (Java or JS ) but me i want to show Java when the selectedValue is java and JavaScript wehn selectedValue is js

Comment: try setting the `selectedValue` to the index of the selected item and then accessing that Picker item's ID's label

Comment: how ? do this exactly

Comment: `const itemRef = useRef();` in the picker component add the reference const `<Picker ref={itemRef} ... /> ;` now try accessing the `itemRef.current` and check if it contains the label prop

Comment: i haven't tested it so feel free to poke around

Comment: yes but i want to assign the label to the useRef(here) when the selected is did it ! how can i do this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241356/discussion-between-abdusalam-mohamed-and-garrix).

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/WO3Rbs1qX check this one

Comment: <Text> {selectedValue} </Text> return nothing !

Comment: What device are you using? i tested it on a physical android and Expo Web

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/whDil-FNE

Comment: me too in the web expo !

Comment: but nothing return

Comment: ref gives undefined in my local